How do I enable ebs-optimization for an ECS service in Terraform?
I have a relatively simple resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {...} definition, but I can't find any option to set ebs-optimization to true. This only seems to be an option if you're defining a aws_instance resource.

Ah, the ebs_optimized setting was in launch_configuration
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_configuration.html#ebs_optimized
